# inequalities for the relation between $\det(A+A')$ and $\det(A)$, where $A$ is positive definite (not necessarily symmetric)

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

I was wondering if there is any relationship (in the form of inequality) between $\det(A+A')$ and $\det(A)$, where $A$ is a positive definite but not necessarily symmetric.

Comment: What do you know about $A'$?

Comment: What does the symbol $A'$ mean? Transpose? Conjugate transpose? Also, what do you mean by a positive definite matrix that is not symmetric? Do you mean a nonreal Hermitian matrix or something else?

Comment: A' := traspose of matrix A   and  by a positive definite matrix I mean x'Ax >0 for any nonzero vector x with the proper dimension.